# Capturing specific number of occurrences using Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to capture **n** of occurrences of the following pattern

`word <p=".."/>`

from the following text:

`already <p="RB"/> ablaze <p="JJ"/> in <p="IN"/> the <p="DT"/> most <p="RBS"/> <head>brilliant <p="JJ"/></head> scarlet <p="JJ"/> . <p="."/>`

I need to capture **n** three before and after the word taged with  for example here: `<head>brilliant <p="JJ"/></head>` so a word before: `most <p="RBS"/>` and a one after: `scarlet <p="JJ"/>` where **n** instance before and after are needed let's say n = 3, I tried this pattern but did not work. Can you correct me?

```
(?<=/> )(.* <p=".*"/>){3}(?= <head>)
```

I know that {#} is used to capture **n** occurrences but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: so you are trying to find out how many times `word <p="..">` occurs in a string?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/27zmil/1

Comment: I'm trying to capture **n** instances of that pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
(?<=/> )([^<>]* <p="[^"]*"/>){3}(?= <head>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/118)